# Accentuation of strings

Tags: python, string

I have a dictionary composed of strings and lists in Python.

```
{'stringhere':[a1,a2,a3], 'anotherstringhere':[a2,a4,a5],....}
```

The problem is that some strings are written as special characters, because of accentuation, like `'ol\xe9'` instead of `'olé'`, for example.

Is it possible to change these strings in orded to achieve the expected (`'olé'`) result? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is the expected result.

Comment: `{'stringhere', [a1,a2,a3], 'anotherstringhere', [a2,a4,a5],....}` is not a dictionary.

Comment: What do you want to change?

Comment: the characters are expressed in unicode

Comment: If this is Python 3, `'ol\xe9'` is the exact same string as `'olé'`, just represented differently.

Comment: `\xe9` is `é`. When you don't `print` a string out, the REPL prints out the output of `repr(obj)`.

Comment: Please reduce your program to the smallest possible program that still demonstrates your problem. Copy-paste that small, complete program into your question. See http://SSCCE.ORG for more information about this debugging technique.

Comment: Yes, but i need to print the string like `'olé'`

Comment: You need to determine the encoding type and render the string as such. utf-8, latin1, etc.

Comment: I found this presentation helpful: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Comment: @Robᵩ: Great link. Also see the official Unicode HOWTO ([2.x](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) or [3.x](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html) as appropriate).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming this is Python 3, `'ol\xe9'` and `'olé'` are just two different representations of the exact same string. You can see this pretty easily:

```
>>> 'ol\xe9' == 'olé'
True
```

If it's Python 2, `'olé'` isn't a valid string at all. `u'olé'` is, and `'ol\xe9'` is an encoding of that Unicode string into bytes in Latin-1 (and in various other character sets).*

---

But either way, your most likely problem isn't what you're asking at all, but just the problem of how to print out the `str`, rather than the `repr`, of each element of a collection. For example, in Python 2:

```
>>> print u'olé'
olé
>>> print [u'olé', u'olé']
[u'ol\xe9', u'ol\xe9']
```

If that's your problem, there are many duplicates on this site, but the short version is that you have to do it manually:

```
>>> s = [u'olé', u'olé']
>>> print u', '.join(s)
olé, olé
```

Of course that doesn't have the brackets or the quotes (or the `u` prefixes). That's because those are part of the representation of the list itself, just as the non-user-friendly representations of the internal strings were. If you want to mix and match different bits, you can; you just have to do it explicitly. For example:

```
>>> print u'[{}]'.format(u', '.join(u"'{}'".format(item) for item in s))
['olé', 'olé']
```

Of course this gets even more complicated if you're trying to print a dictionary whose values are lists of strings, so you're probably going to want to write some wrapper functions to help you instead of writing triply-nested expressions…

---

* Actually, this isn't quite true. In fact, `'olé'` is a valid string literal, as long as the bytes that your source file encodes that into can be decoded by the source-file coding you specified in a header comment. But it may not be a very useful one. Unless your text editor, your coding declaration, and either the explicit `decode` calls in your code, or your console's encoding, all match exactly, you will get confused and end up with mojibake all over the place. So it's best to avoid this entirely; either use Unicode literals, or byte literals with explicit byte sequences for the encoding you're expecting.

Comment: A simple way to get a human readable representation of a dictionary is to use pprint. `from pprint import pprint` `pprint(s)`

Comment: @audiodude: All `pprint` does is improve the layout of the (possibly nested) collections' members; it still prints the `repr` of each (non-collection) member. For example, `pprint([u'olé'])` prints out `[u'ol\xe9']` on my system (Apple pre-installed CPython 2.7.2). So, that doesn't solve the problem at all. (In fact, the examples even show this, printing a bunch of strings, all with their quotes, and sometimes `u` prefixes.)

Comment: You're right, I didn't realize that

Answer (score 0):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
a = {'olé' : 1}
for i in a:
    print i, a[i]

Output: olé 1
```

So what do you need, please explain?

Comment: I just need to print the string like you did, but even if i put the first line of your code in mine, it does not work. It keeps printing with special characters.

Comment: Can you put some piece of code? Do you have the header on top, did you encode or decode the strings?

Comment: @LuizSantos: You need to actually save the file as UTF-8 too. If your text editor is saving the file as, say, Latin-1 or cp1252, and you stick a UTF-8 coding declaration on it, it's going to be mojibake. (Except in emacs, which will figure out the problem and demand you fix it one way or the other.)

Comment: But this doesn't really solve the original problem. You can always create the string literal `u'ol\xe9'` without even needing a coding declaration; either way, you still need to know how to print it out.